# How to check if checkbox doesn't have a label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of checkboxes, some of them have labels and some do not. I want to be able to give a certain style to all checkboxes without a label. Any ideas this could be done?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="publish"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="delete" name="delete" /><label for="delete">Delete</label>
```

Comment: Edit your question and add your HTML.(+ what have you tried?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
   if (!$("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").length) {
      $(this).css(styles);
   }
});
```

It's also possible for you to do this with CSS alone depending upon what your HTML looks like, but you can't compare `id` and `for` in CSS.

Comment: How would you do it with css? I could do html differently

Comment: You can use the sibling selectors.  `label + input` in CSS selects an input that is the directly following sibling of a `<label>`.

Comment: the problem was on my part apparently, i fixed it already, thanks:) works now

Answer (score 2):

In order for labels to work, they must have a `for` attribute that matches the input element's `id`, or must be an ancestor of the input element.  This function takes a jQuery element or string selector as an argument and checks if there are any labels that have a `for` attribute with a value that matches the element's `id` or if there is a label ancestor.

```
function hasLabel(el) {
    el = $(el); // ensure jQuery-wrapped
    return (
        el.closest('label').length > 0 ||
        $('label[for="' + el.attr('id') + '"]').length > 0
    );
}
```

Comment: That's not true.  A `for` attribute is not needed if the label is a parent of the form element:  `<label>Enable <input type="checkbox" /></label>`

Comment: You should ensure, if `el` is an jQuery-Object. Do `$(el)` before calling `.attr()`. Then you can call `hasLabel` with an `'#selector'`.

Comment: Thank you, I took all of your input into consideration and updated.